# Azure DevOps REST - add Administrator for a Team

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have been using the following endpoint to add an Administrator for a Team within a project.

```
$addTeamAdminUri = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{projuid}/_api/_identity/AddTeamAdmins?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
$teamAdminConfiguration = '{"teamId":"<teamguid>","newUsersJson":"[]","existingUsersJson":"[\"<userguid>\"]"}'
```

Until about a week or so ago, this would work with a Personal Access Token with Custom Scope where only some of the permissions were enabled.

However now, even if ALL the PAT permissions are enabled under Custom defined Access I still get a 401. The only way I can get this working is if I give the PAT Full Access. PAT is not expired. Anyone else experience this? I would prefer not to give Full Access.

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Answer (score 0):

What is the PAT scopes you set to run the REST API?
Please try the PAT with the scope "**Project and Team:** **`Read, write, & manage`**" to see if it can work.

[image]

In addition, I did not find the RESI API you are using from the Microsoft document. Where did you find this API? Please share the link of it. Thanks.

Comment: Those granular permissions used to work until recently. Now it requires full access. 

Ref: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-add-team-administrator-through-azure-devops/821001